# PHP Exec Crontab Not Doing Anything

Tags: php, exec, cron, shell-exec

I am trying to set up a cron job using a PHP script. This works fine on my computer running XAMPP but when I try it on my web host (Just Host) it's not adding it to the list of cron jobs. Here is the PHP code:

```
exec('crontab cronfile.txt');
```

cronfile.txt Contents:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/-username-/public_html/cron/cron.php 1
```

This does however work when I add it through cPanel and I can view any cron jobs by using shell_exec('crontab -l'). Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I recommend adding the cronjobs via the cpanel, not trough PHP. IF you need to add your own scheduled tasks from the PHP application, setup a cronjob for every 5minutes to check if it has something to do.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely Apache is running as a different user than `username`, so it won't update `username`s crontab file.  Run the script

```
<?php phpinfo()
```

and verify which user Apache is running as.

On my system, I see the following

```
User/Group  apache(48)/48
```

Comment: Calling system('whoami'); returns my username

Answer (score 0):

You should use this `exec('crontab /tmp/cronfile.txt')`
and it will work.
You can add every script to this file.
example:

```
touch /tmp/cronfile.txt
vi /tmp/cronfile.txt
* * * * * path-to-script
* * * * * path-to-script2 
.
.
finally
crontab /tmp/cronfile.txt
crontab -l you will see your cron list
```